# Angular UI Router only loads first declared child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-child, angular-ui-router, nested-views

Whichever child state I place first in my routing setup is the one that loads. Everything else works just fine. Resolve dependencies are inherited as they should, the view is rendered and controller instanciated. But the second child state is totally ignored...

Routing in app.coffee

```
$stateProvider
.state 'feed',
  abstract: true
  url: '/'
  templateUrl: 'views/feed.html'
  controller: 'FeedController'
  resolve: (a bunch of them :P)
.state 'feed.timeline',
  url: ''
  views:
    'timeline':
      templateUrl: 'views/partials/feed/timeline.html'
      controller: 'FeedTimelineController'
.state 'feed.trending',
  url: ''
  views:
    'trending':
      templateUrl: 'views/partials/feed/trending.html'
      controller: 'FeedTrendingController'
```

placeholders in index.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

in 'views/feed.html':

```
<div ui-view="trending"></div>
<div ui-view="timeline"></div>
```

I really appreciate any help, tried everything I could think of and feeling exhausted after hours searching wikis, groups, google, stackoverflow... Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the url property in your child states or make them distinct? E.g. /trending, /timeline

Comment: @rawphl that wouldn't be the wanted output, really was just a case of a child state with two views instead of two separated child states. But thanks a lot for your time! Appreciate it

Comment: You need url's in your child states.  You usually leave one of the child state's urls blank if the parent is an abstract state, this way when you navigate to the parent it will default to the child with the empty url.  But yeah, it seems like you probably want subviews, not separate child states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the ui-router correctly. A state basically corresponds to a URL (except when it is abstract). I guess you want to have one state that puts stuff into the two subviews of your state 'feed'.

```
$stateProvider
.state 'feed',
  abstract: true
  url: '/'
  templateUrl: 'views/feed.html'
  controller: 'FeedController'
  resolve: (a bunch of them :P)
.state 'feed.index',
  url: ''
  views:
    'timeline@feed':
      templateUrl: 'views/partials/feed/timeline.html'
      controller: 'FeedTimelineController'
    'trending@feed':
      templateUrl: 'views/partials/feed/trending.html'
      controller: 'FeedTrendingController'
```

You don't have to choose 'feed.index' as the name but it has to start with 'feed.' so it is a child state.

Comment: thank you very much! I feel so stupid looking at the solution right now. I guess I should stop overnight coding.

Thanks again, man